# 2D Camera transformations in MakingGamesWithBen tutorial

Tags: c++, camera, 2d-games, glm-math

I am following the Advanced C++/ Graphics tutorails by MakingGamesWithBen and I made it to the Camera2D episode and it confused me (episode here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rycaqr3tDRA&list=PLSPw4ASQYyymu3PfG9gxywSPghnSMiOAW&index=23).

I have done graphics programming in the past, but it was all in 3D and a while ago. I learnt that the transformation matrices have to be applied (multiplied) in a certain order, and if I remember correctly, it was first apply rotation, then scale, then translate, then apply the projection matrix. So ProjMat * T * S * R. So basically, all transformations are done in world coordinates and then transformed into screen coordinates.

However, in the tutorial I am following right now, it is done this way:

```
glm::vec3 translate(-m_position.x + m_screenWidth / 2, -m_position.y + m_screenHeight / 2, 0.0f);
m_cameraMatrix = glm::translate(m_orthoMatrix, translate);          
glm::vec3 scale(m_scale, m_scale, 0.0f);
m_cameraMatrix = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), scale) * m_cameraMatrix;
```

It seems like it is doing this: S * (O * T). Translate in world coordinates, transform to screen coordinates, then scale in screen coordinates.
I tried doing this the way I would think it should work (P * T * S) and the scene does not show up.
I am confused as to how and why this works. Or maybe I am reading this incorrectly.

The +screenWidth/2 and height parts in translate are for centering the camera. The m_orthoMatrix is a normal orthographic projection matrix. M_scale is not zoom (1/scale) which also throws me off.

Could anyone shed some light on this matter?

Comment: Why do you think it should work that way?

Comment: @immibis why do I think what should work what way?

Comment: why do you think it should be P * T * S?

Comment: @immibis because scaling should go first to be done around the origin, then translation to position it in the world, and last project it to the screen. I could buy first scaling, then projecting it and last translating it in screen coordinates, but usually scaling and rotating are done in local coordinates so that they are applied to the object while it is in the origin.

Comment: Are they trying to scale the object or the camera?

Comment: @immibis the object. That matrix is later used to modify the vertices of the object being drawn.

Comment: I mean is it *trying* to adjust the camera or the object? Since really moving/zooming the camera just means moving/zooming the objects, backwards.

Comment: @immibis That is what I was saying. I think it is the object. Since it is not being modified in any other way before multiplying it with the vertices of the scene, it seems like it is set up from the perspective of "we are moving the object."